# java code to get ip address class

Tags: java

I wrote this code to ask the user to input an ip address and it worked using regex, but then I want to tell the user which class is this ip depending on the range (0-126)class A, (128-191)class b, (192-224)class c, and 127 is an exception "loop back", I don't know how to do it, can somebody help?

Here's my code:

```
public class main {


        public static void main(String[]args){

        String IP="";
        Scanner Scr = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a valid network IP:");
        // thanks to this link http://www.mkyong.com/regular-expressions/how-to-validate-ip-address-with-regular-expression/
        String pattern = "^([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\.([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\.([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\.([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])$";
        //String pattern = "[0-255][.][0-255][.][0-255][.][0-255]";
        boolean matches = false;
        do{

            IP = Scr.nextLine();
            matches = Pattern.matches(pattern, IP);
            if(matches==false)
                System.out.println("wrong range");
        }while(!matches);

        Scr.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex you're using contains [capturing groups](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html). You could use those to extract the first number group, then convert it to `int` and use that to decide what you need to print.

Instead of the static `Pattern.matches` method, you'd need a `Pattern` object, which can be used to create a `Matcher` for a particular string. That one gives access to capturing groups.

Your code could look like this in the end:

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\.([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\.([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\.([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])$");
    boolean matches = false;
    do {
        IP = Scr.nextLine();
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(IP);
        matches = matcher.matches();
        if (matches == false)
            System.out.println("wrong range");
        else {
            int number = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1));
            System.out.println("first group is " + number);
            if (number < 127)
                System.out.println("Class A");
            else ...
        ...
```